# Is it possible to make LI elements overflow vertically in UL?

Tags: css, html-lists

The question is

```
<ul>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
<li>test5</li>
<li>test6</li>
<li>test7</li>
<li>test8</li>
<li>test9</li>
<li>test10</li>
<li>test11</li>
<li>test12</li>
</ul>
```

is like this... and the result is

```
test1   test2    test3
test4   test5    test6
test7   test7    test9
test10   test12    test12
```

and i prefer it like this :P

```
test1   test5    test9
test2   test6    test10
test3   test7    test11
test4   test8    test12
```

So guys is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Multiple CSS3 column-count Property`for your desired result see the code for your requirement :-

**HTML**

```
<ul class="three-col">
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
<li>test5</li>
<li>test6</li>
<li>test7</li>
<li>test8</li>
<li>test9</li>
<li>test10</li>
<li>test11</li>
<li>test12</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.three-col {
       -moz-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-gap: 20px;
       -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
       list-style-type:none;
}
```

I think this will also help you :- http://tinkerbin.com/KLNj5ghL

Comment: Yeh... all of you are true but my list is Dynamic... so i can't separate it... :D and the column is not really good :D... Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Hi now you can used to `css3` properties  `column-count`

Css

```
ul{
list-style:none;
}
li{
border-bottom:solid 1px red;
}

ul
{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
```

***[live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/CBlyGwyD)***

***[more info](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)***

Answer (score 0):

Great solution by Rohit Azad

But IE 6-9 doesn't support the CSS3 coloumn...
If you want a Full Browser Support, you can (a little bit ugly, i know...) use this version...

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>test5</li>
<li>test6</li>
<li>test7</li>
<li>test8</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>test9</li>
<li>test10</li>
<li>test11</li>
<li>test12</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
  border:1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  list-style:none;
}
```

Greez

Comment: Yeh... all of you are true but my list is Dynamic... so i can't separate it... :D and the column is not really good :D... Thanks guys